# Zero-crossing returns high values

Tags: c++, matlab, signal-processing

I have a 2D array containing blocks of data, and I have created a function that calculates how many times each value crosses zero.

I am using MatLab and trying to convert the code and MatLab returns 287 values for the zero-crossing and in the C++ code, the values are extremely high and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the Matlab code:

```
function f = zerocross(vector)

% This function simply reports the number of times
% that the input vector crosses the zero boundary

len = length(vector);
currsum = 0;
prevsign = 0;

for i = 1:len
currsign = sign(vector(i));
if (currsign * prevsign) == -1 
  currsum = currsum + 1;
end
if currsign ~= 0
  prevsign = currsign;
end
end

f = currsum;
```

And my C++ code:

```
vector<iniMatrix> Audio::filter(vector<iniMatrix>&blocks, double sumThres, double ZeroThres)
{
 double totalSum = this->width * sumThres;
 double totalZero = this->width * ZeroThres;

int currZero = 0;
int currsum = 0;

int prevsign = 0;


for(unsigned i=0; (i < 287); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; (j < blocks.size()); j++)
    {
        currZero = sign<double>(blocks[j][i]);

        if(currZero * prevsign == -1)
        {
            currsum++;
        }

        if(currZero != 0)
        {
            prevsign = currZero;
        }
    }
    cout << currsum << endl;
}

return blocks;
```

Sign function:

```
int sign(T n)
{
  if(n < 0) return -1;
  if(n > 0) return 1;
  return n;
}
```

The values that I should (and matlab give) are:

6, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10 .., 11, ..., 9, ...

The values that I get:

212, 337, 118, 84, ...., 348, ..., 92

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

This is how I have my loop now:

```
for(int q=0; (q < 287); q++)
{
    for(unsigned i=0; (i < blocks.size()); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned j=0; (j < blocks[0].size()); j++)
        {
            currZero = sign<double>(blocks[i][j]);
            cout << currZero << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl;

    }
    //cout << currZero << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the iniMatrix ??

Comment: @RamiJarrar iniMatrix is a 2D vector typedef .. Ok, so it seems that if I output "currZero" then it just displays the same values for each block, this is wrong

Comment: Is your intent to perform the check for each block ("row"), one at a time?  If so, then you should swap the order of your inner and outer loops.  Your loop is iterating over the matrix in more of a column-centric order - you'll hit `blocks[0][0], blocks[1][0], ..., blocks[n][0], blocks[1][0], blocks[1][1]`, etc.  In other words you are comparing the i'th element of each block, rather than comparing the elements within each block.

Comment: as @atkretsch said you should change blocks[j][i] to blocks[i][j].

Comment: your C++ implementation of sign() is not equal to Matlab's sign(). In case of zero, the result is zero.

Comment: Just swapping the index operators won't work (note that `j` is range-bound to the length of `blocks`) - he needs to change the structure of the loop so that `blocks.size()` is the outer bound and `287` is the inner bound.  The variable names don't really matter, but by convention it would result in switching `i` and `j`

Comment: @atkretsch Please see my edit loop (at the bottom of my o/p .. did you mean something like this or..?

Comment: blocks[0].size() ,, this must be blocks[i].size() .

Comment: @Phorce I don't understand what the outer loop (`q` from 0 to 287) is for.  But the two inner loops are closer to what I'd expect to see, though as @RamiJarrar pointed out you need to use `blocks[i].size()` in the innermost for loop.

Comment: @atkretsch I understand what you mean, I was wondering that one too! In Matlab in prints out 287 times for some reason.

Comment: @Serg: Why would it not be equal? In Matlab: `sign([-2 0 2]) == [-1 0 1]`. His implementation is just a little verbose (`return (n>0)-(n<0);` would suffice)

Comment: For what input `vector` to `zerocross` will you get the desired output values you provide? Can you edit an example input `vector` into your question?

Comment: why is blocks two dimensional?  It looks like vector in your Matlab is only 1 dimensional.  Perhaps blocks should just be iniMatrix rather than vector<iniMatrix>?

Answer (score 0):

Heavy use of for loop's in Matlab has traditionally usually been a bad idea, as Matlab's JIT compiler isn't (or wasn't) very fast (at least not compared to native C code). I am guessing you wrote the C++ code to speed up computation, but maybe an alternative would be to write code the 'matlab way':

```matlab
vector = rand(1e7,1)-0.1;
zero_crossings = sum(diff(array<0)~=0);
```

Though I just tested on Matlab 2015b, in the vectorized code is only about twice as fast:

```
function test()

    function currsum = zerocross(vector)

        % This function simply reports the number of times
        % that the input vector crosses the zero boundary

        len = length(vector);
        currsum = 0;
        prevsign = 0;

        for i = 1:len
            currsign = sign(vector(i));
            if (currsign * prevsign) == -1
                currsum = currsum + 1;
            end
            if currsign ~= 0
                prevsign = currsign;
            end
        end
    end

    function f = zerocross_vectorized(array)
        f = sum(diff(array<0)~=0);
    end

    array = rand(1e5,1e3)-0.1;

    % test for loop
    t = tic;
    crossings = nan(1,size(array,2));
    for column = 1:size(array,2)
        vector = array(:,column);
        crossings(column) = zerocross(vector);
    end
    disp(crossings(1:5))
    fprintf(1,'For loop: Calculated in %0.4f seconds\n',toc(t));

    % test vectorized
    t = tic;
    crossings = zerocross_vectorized(array);
    disp(crossings(1:5))
    fprintf(1,'Vectorized: Calculated in %0.4f seconds\n',toc(t));

end
```

Which results in:

```
>> zerocross
       18208       17884       17902       17734       17988

For loop: Calculated in 1.7186 seconds
       18208       17884       17902       17734       17988

Vectorized: Calculated in 0.9695 seconds
```